# Is macbook air 501 64-bit or 32-bit? Which version of Eclipse should I choose?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

The information from "unname -a" tells that it is i386. But I found that some applications in the Activity Monitor are with types "Intel 64". What's more, the System Profiler says:64-bit Kernel and Extensions, no. So, which version of Eclipse should I choose, 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: A 32bit architecture cannot support a 64bit application whereas a 64bit architecture can support 32bit apps. I would imagine you should go with the 64bit version of eclipse. Though it doesn't really matter which version if your computing platform is 64bit.

Comment: @DarkStar1 so it means the macbook air 501 is using 64-bit architecture?

Comment: You can [run 64-bit apps even when your kernel runs in 32-bit mode](http://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-64bit.html). The Macbook Air CPU is 64-bit.

Comment: most computing platforms have been 64bit since before the air ever came out or even before Apple started using the Intel architecture.. so yes it is 64bit hardware architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same of Java, try

```
java -version
```

32-bit:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

64-bit:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode) // so I should choose the 64-bit version?

Comment: So, I'd go with 64, otherwise Eclipse will throw an error at startup (JVM exited with -1 status code or similar)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `sysctl`:

```
bash$ /usr/sbin/sysctl hw.cpu64bit_capable
hw.cpu64bit_capable: 1
bash$
```

You don't really care about the hardware though.  Eclipse cares about which java you are running.  [rekin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623692/is-macbook-air-501-64-bit-or-32-bit-which-version-of-eclipse-should-i-choose/6623709#6623709) answer for Eclipse.

*Note:* I added this answer just in case anyone stumbles across this in the future.

Comment: `hw.cpu64bit_capable: 1` so it means it's 64-bit?

Comment: Yes.  You are running a 64-bit JVM as well so I would go for the 64-bit version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

See the nice article [Booting into 64-bit mode (Snow Leopard)](http://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-64bit.html) on how to test whether your machine is 64-bit capable and how to boot into 64-bit mode, if you wish to.

The interesting part:

> With 32-bit firmware, you cannot boot into 64-bit kernel; it’s not possible.
>
> To determine if your Mac has 32-bit or 64-bit firmware, copy/paste the following command shown in red into Terminal (Terminal is found in the /Applications/Utilities folder):

```
llcMP:~ lloyd$ ioreg -l -p IODeviceTree | grep firmware-abi
    | |   "firmware-abi" = <"EFI64">
```

> As shown above, the firmware-abi has the value EFI64, indicating that my Mac Pro is 64-bit capable. If it reads EFI32, then your Mac cannot be booted into a 64-bit kernel.

**Edit:** Since the original color is lost, the command one has to copy and paste in the terminal is: `ioreg -l -p IODeviceTree | grep firmware-abi`